# How to capture logbook stdout output with pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, logbook

I want to test that logging is working but I cannot capture the logs from logbook with pytest.

Here is a simple example that demos the problem:

```py
import sys
import logbook


logbook.StreamHandler(sys.stdout, level=logbook.INFO).push_application()


def use_print():
    print("This is a dummy message using print")


def test_print(capsys):
    use_print()
    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    assert err == ""
    assert "dummy" in out


def use_logbook():
    log = logbook.Logger("Dummy Log")
    log.info("This is a dummy message using logbook")


def test_logbook(capsys):
    use_logbook()
    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    assert err == ""
    assert "dummy" in out
```

Both `print` and `logbook` output to stdout, but pytest only captures the output of stdout when using print but not logbook.

How do I get pytest to capture the stdout of logbook?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`capfd`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/capture.html#accessing-captured-output-from-a-test-function) instead of `capsys`.